# Oculus application enable mode developper for oculus quest 2

Tags: android, adb, unreal-engine4, oculus, oculusquest

I'm facing a really weird  bug in oculus application for android devices.
I have 6 oculus devices and I'm developing a project using unreal engine  4 everything  was normal until  sudelly my oculus device all of them refuse to connecr with UE4 or even side quest ( no device found showing in side quest) i tryied to install  and desinstall th ADB but always  showing  the same problem no divices found I did a lot of research and the only solution  is to enabled the mode developper in oculus app ( I enable ot the first time I connecr to the occlus App for the 6 devices ) I open the app but I could'nr find the mode developper at all it was there like 2 days ago and now it's gone I try older verson I install it in different  verson of phone but I get nothing please dose anyone face this problem before or have no idea because I'm stuck in this for a while and couldn't continue  developing my game
Ps : I tried to factory reset  all the occulus  device and create new account  with facebook connect it to tha oculus App but still  the same problem
[image: Image of oculus App with no developer mode]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I couldn't find the developer mode option in the headset settings of my Oculus app on my iPhone. I saw the pinned comment on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iSncojIFZQ) which said that as of Feb 2021, Oculus requires developers who have an Oculus developer account to verify their accounts using their credit/debit card. I went to my Oculus account, profile>payment methods. I then added my credit card and now the Developer mode option appears on my phone app! Turn this on and if you do `adb devices` on your terminal your quest headset should show up.